# Latest chrome 37.x.x font looks weird

Tags: google-chrome

I'm not sure if others have the same problem, after upgraded my Chrome to latest version (37.x.x), all fonts  become thinner and weird, look below capture,

[image]

As you can see, 'Neeson' looks a little bit weird, it should be one word, but in fact 'ees' were combined together, the gap between 'N' and 'ees' is obvious, as well as  'ees' and 'on'.

Anther one is 'About Chrome' menu is gone.

[image]

I tried everything like reset to default setting, but seems doesn't work at all, is this a bug or somewhat, I'm using a 15.3 inch screen with high DPI (1920x1080).

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have the same problem. Couldn't find a way to downgrade Chrome to 35.

Comment: I found the way how to downgrade to 35, **control panel** -> **Programs and Features** -> **DOUBLE click 'Google Chrome'** -> check the remove profile checkbox, then open any browser navigate to www.google.com, from the suggested link download and install chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling DirectWrite would help, it works for me: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/chrome-font-rendering-windows/